# What is Causal Dimension in DWH

Tags: data-warehouse

Please help me in understanding the concept of Causal dimension.
It will really help if there is some site/link which I can refer.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://www.kimballgroup.com/1996/11/02/causal-not-casual-dimensions/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from technical point of view, a causal dimension is a dimension like any other (product, employee, store etc.). Just like a time dimension stores information about date and time at which a fact occured, causal dimension stores information about causes of the fact.

For example, fact table about sold car insurance policies can have product, time and employee dimensions. It also can have a causal dimension, such as "reason" or "promotion". This enables success rate measurement for the marketing department.

I think that the only reason someone made up a name for such dimension, is to emphasize its meaning. It is a very meaningful dimension (especially to marketing departments). However, just like  it is mentioned in the link in the Rolf's comment, there is usually not a direct connection between the fact and the causal dimensions. For example, company selling those car insurance policies may not have a field where they enter the reason of the customer's purchase. So it would be a very good thing for them to create such a field in the line-of-business system's database and make sure that the sales staff asks each customer about the reason of their purchase or how did they hear about the company. Then this field should be used as a source for their causal dimension.